# Saving a database function in a table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am deploying an application at one of our vendor. We have few special character that needs to be removed using a function. Vendor is really slow with any changes that we request.

I have access to one of the configuration table that we use to save configuration table.

I want to save a SQL function in the table column that I will fetch at run-time and will execute it.

I am not sure if its a good programming practice. Please suggest if this should not be used then why or is there any other way to do it?

Database is SQL Server. Suggest if it's a good programming practice.

Comment: "I am not sure if its a good programming practice" I'm sure it's not...

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: Please provide your function and expected result

Comment: @Marzouk as i have access to that table i can modify the function as i encounter new special characters, . But i am not sure if its a good programming practice.

Comment: @Devart i am not asking the code. I am asking if its a good programming practice and if not then why?

Comment: A general rule of thumb: If you have to ask yourself if something is a good idea/good practice, it's probably not.

Comment: I actually think it is fine! Turning code into configuration is a very common practice (particularly to speed up delivery of common requirement changes), so is fine. If the only place you can store configuration is this specific table, then that's a constraint you have to work under, so your proposed solution is fine. My only suggestion would be that if you can just store the special characters in the configuration table, rather than a SQL function (as this is a possible attack vector - dynamic SQL) that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

A better practice would be to write your function in such a way that you don't have to change it every time a new special character pops up.

Instead of writing a function that filters out a predefined set of special characters, why don't you write a function that allows a predefined set of non-special characters?   Then you should never have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [Computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) in sql server, for me it's not a good practice depending on the scenario that you are trying to achieve but I think this might help you